# Boundness Theorem of continuous functions by finding a finite open cover

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a homework question that asks to prove that continuous functions are bounded on a close interval by utilizing the facts that (1) if $f$ is a continuous function then at each point of the function there exists an open interval on which it bounded (2) that the collection of all these open intervals is an open cover of some arbitrary closed interval $X$ and (3) that a finite subset of this open cover is also an open cover of $X$.

I've successfully proved (1) and (3), [(2) is given], and I suppose that I can prove the boundness theorem by performing a union on all the elements of (3); I just don't understand is why we couldn't perform such an operation on (2).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a cover $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of your interval and you know that $f|_{U_i}$ is bounded by a constant, say $M_i$. Then $f$ is bounded by $\sup\limits_{i \in I} M_i$. If your cover $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is not finite, you cannot guarantee that this supremum is finite. Therefore you choose a finite subcover and then, since the supremum of finitely many numbers is clearly finite, you get that $f$ is bounded.